Are there any large swiss with good playing standard that are not rated?
Chess players who are improving in the USA have good reasons to avoid increasing their ratings as prize money is often high in tournaments with a rating ceiling.   The rules for such tournaments include having to declare all ratings to the organizers.
But clearly however much study has been done, a lot of over-the-board (OTB) practice would be needed to pick up the 10k.
